# Applying effect to overlay Background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Greeting,

I have 3 background image will overlay each other when scrolled. So i created the html like below :

```
<body>
<section class="bg1"></section>
<section class="bg2"></section>
<section class="bg3"></section>
<section class="content">
     <h1>This is main content</h1> 
</section>
</body>
```

And i put the css :

```
 body {
    font-family : 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("http://idproz.com/rasterman/img/bg1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
bg2.scrolled {
    background:url("http://idproz.com/rasterman/img/bg2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position : absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .4;
}
.bg3.scrolled2 {
    background:url("http://idproz.com/rasterman/img/bg3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position : absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .4;
}
.content {
    height: 1800px;
}
```

Finally the script :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var JarakScroll = 150; // jarak scrol
    var JumlahJarakPasScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (JumlahJarakPasScroll > JarakScroll) {
        jQuery('.bg2').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
        jQuery('.bg2').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var JarakScroll = 700; // jarak scrol
    var JumlahJarakPasScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (JumlahJarakPasScroll > JarakScroll) {
        jQuery('.bg3').addClass('scrolled2');
    } else {
        jQuery('.bg3').removeClass('scrolled2');
    }
});

(function ($) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    //cache a reference to the banner
    var banner = $("body");

    // set initial banner background position
    banner.css('backgroundPosition', x + 'px' + '' + y + 'px');

    // scroll up background position every 90 milliseconds
    window.setInterval(function () {
        banner.css("backgroundPosition", x + 'px' + ' ' + y + 'px');
        y--;
        //x--;

        //if you need to scroll image horizontally -
        // uncomment x and comment y

    }, 20);
})(jQuery);
```

I need help to applying effect for the background image when scroll meet some point. At the moment its just show up without any transition or effect.

Any type of effect is doesnt matter.

Here the fiddle [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/QbEua/1/)

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you want to archieve. Should the background constantly scroll without user scrolling (as demonstrated in your Fiddle)? And the three background images should cross-fade? Because in your Fiddle the first background ends after a while and then, that page is black. Is the user's scroll event involved somehow? Please correct your sentences and add a detailled description of what should happen on/at which event/time.

Comment: Nope, its not need to constantly scroll. Sorry for bad english.